# Enable the datepicker from a particular date

Tags: iphone

I am making an iphone app on one of the view I am using a date picker. I have an another date which I am fetching from the database. Now I want that the date picker enable from the selected date so that user couldn't get unable to select the same date again. Is there any way to enable the picker from selected date. If anyone know please help me.

```
-(void)findextenddate
{
    NSLog(@"count:%@",adddatetime);
    addatimeclass = adddatetime;
    endnsdate = [addatimeclass objectAtIndex:[addatimeclass count]-1];
    endnsdate1 = (NSDate*) endnsdate; 
    NSLog(@"formatdate:%@",endnsdate1);
}

-(IBAction)clicktoextend:(id)sender
{
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]init];
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];
    [actionsheet showInView:[self.view superview]];
    [actionsheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
    pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

    pickerView.minimumDate = endnsdate1 ;
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    //Add picker to action sheet
    [actionsheet addSubview:pickerView];
    subviews = [actionsheet subviews];


    [[subviews objectAtIndex:SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)]; 
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];
    [pickerView release];
    [actionsheet release];
}
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UIDatePicker has `minimumDate` property which serves exactly that purpose

Comment: I have edited my answer, Vladimir please check the code which I am implementing and tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Minkle It's hard to tell, have you checked that endnsdate1 is valid when you set minimumDate? you don't call findextenddate anywhere so it may be just not initialized...

Comment: I am calling findextenddate in viewwillapppear method. And what do u mean by validation of endnsdate? I am mot getting u.

Comment: print endnsdate1 in clicktoextend method - if it has correct value

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
datePicker.minimumDate=YOUR date object
```

this function disable all dates before your date

Comment: I tried it already but didn't get the result. Ok, let me try it again may be I am doing some mistake.

Comment: if you use minimumdate and setdate options.you get your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you need to set the date of the picker to the one you are fetching from the database, you can do so via the `- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

If you need to enable the picker from that date ONWARDS (no past dates), set the `minimumDate` property as is suggested by the earlier answers.